# Mongoengine Connection Failure

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, mongoengine, celerybeat

I am trying to run celery beat for my project, but it's giving me the following error.

The celery worker is running fine.

I am using Python 3.9

Using MongoDB:  6.0.11

```
    raise ConnectionFailure(err_msg)
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: A different connection with alias `default` was already registered. Use disconnect() first
```

installed packages with its versions:

Package                           Version

--------------------------------- ------------

amqp                              2.6.1

asgiref                           3.7.2

async-timeout                     4.0.3

billiard                          3.6.4.0

boto3                             1.28.65

botocore                          1.31.65

Bottleneck                        1.3.5

celery                            4.4.7

celerybeat-mongo                  0.2.0

certifi                           2023.7.22

cffi                              1.16.0

chardet                           5.2.0

charset-normalizer                3.3.0

click                             8.1.7

click-didyoumean                  0.3.0

click-plugins                     1.1.1

click-repl                        0.3.0

cmdstanpy                         1.2.0

colorama                          0.4.6

convertdate                       2.4.0

coreapi                           2.3.3

coreschema                        0.0.4

cryptography                      41.0.4

cycler                            0.12.1

Cython                            3.0.4

Django                            4.2.6

django-encrypted-model-fields     0.6.5

django-rest-framework-mongoengine 3.4.1

django-rest-swagger               2.2.0

djangorestframework               3.14.0

dnspython                         2.4.2

docutils                          0.20.1

ephem                             4.1.2

fernet                            1.0.1

gevent                            23.9.1

greenlet                          3.0.0

holidays                          0.35

idna                              3.4

imgkit                            1.2.3

importlib-resources               6.1.0

itypes                            1.2.0

Jinja2                            3.1.2

jmespath                          1.0.1

kiwisolver                        1.4.4

kombu                             4.6.11

LunarCalendar                     0.0.9

MarkupSafe                        2.1.3

matplotlib                        3.4.3

mkl-service                       2.4.0

mongoengine                       0.20.0

numexpr                           2.8.4

numpy                             1.22.4

openapi-codec                     1.3.2

packaging                         23.2

pandas                            1.5.3

Pillow                            9.4.0

pip                               23.3

plotly                            5.17.0

prompt-toolkit                    3.0.39

prophet                           1.1.4

pyaes                             1.6.1

pycparser                         2.21

PyMeeus                           0.5.12

pymongo                           3.13.0

pyparsing                         3.1.1

pystan                            2.19.1.1

python-dateutil                   2.8.2

pytz                              2023.3.post1

redis                             5.0.1

requests                          2.31.0

s3transfer                        0.7.0

scipy                             1.11.3

setuptools                        68.0.0

simplejson                        3.19.2

six                               1.16.0

sqlparse                          0.4.4

stanio                            0.3.0

tenacity                          8.2.3

tornado                           6.2

tqdm                              4.66.1

typing_extensions                 4.8.0

tzdata                            2023.3

uritemplate                       4.1.1

urllib3                           2.0.7

vine                              1.3.0

wcwidth                           0.2.8

wheel                             0.41.2

XlsxWriter                        3.1.8

zipp                              3.17.0

zope.event                        5.0

zope.interface                    6.1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 499, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 491, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 415, in execute
    return cls(
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 308, in run_from_argv
    return self.handle_argv(prog_name,
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 393, in handle_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 253, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\beat.py", line 109, in run
    return beat().run()
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\beat.py", line 81, in run
    self.start_scheduler()
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\beat.py", line 100, in start_scheduler
    print(self.banner(service))
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\beat.py", line 122, in banner
    c.reset(self.startup_info(service))),
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\beat.py", line 132, in startup_info
    scheduler = service.get_scheduler(lazy=True)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celery\beat.py", line 657, in get_scheduler
    return symbol_by_name(self.scheduler_cls, aliases=aliases)(
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\celerybeatmongo\schedulers.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._mongo = mongoengine.connect(db, host=host, alias=alias)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\condaenv_python3.10\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\connection.py", line 401, in connect
    raise ConnectionFailure(err_msg)
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: A different connection with alias `default` was already registered. Use disconnect() first
```

I tried to add the following line in the code where I am connecting mongoengine

disconnect()

but it did not work.

now I am expecting that celery beat should run.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
import mongoengine

mongoengine.disconnect(alias='default')


mongoengine.connect('your-db-name', alias='default')
```